# Adding up numbers in Portuguese is strange

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, alphametic

My friend from Portugal said that 2 + 2 is 8 in Portuguese. And he could prove it. I did not understand it at first. But then he showed me the following equation:

```
  D O I S
  D O I S
+ ________
  O I T O
```

Ah, now it is clear. Two is "dois" and eight is "oito" in Portuguese. And the equation above makes perfect sense. Could you solve the single one solution that explain this?

**Rules**: D, O, I, S and T are a number between 0 - 9. Each one is unique.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> From $S+S\equiv O\pmod{10}$, we know $O$ is even. From $O+O$, we know $O\le4$ because $2O$ doesn't carry (otherwise $O$ would be odd because $D+D$ is even). Therefore $I$ is [doubly even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singly_and_doubly_even) ($I\equiv 2O\pmod{10}$ and $O\equiv 2S\pmod{10}$), and because $2I$ doesn't carry, $I=4$ and $O=2$. $D=S\pm5$ (we have $D+D=S+S\equiv O \pmod{10}$), and $2D$ doesn't carry (otherwise there would be five letters in the answer), and so $S=6$ (because $O=2$, $S$ is either $1$ or $6$) and $D=1$. Finally, $T=2I+1=9$, so the sum is $1246+1246=2492$.

Comment: You haven't given a value for $T$.

Comment: *»Therefore **I** is …,«* why? how can one know that whithout looking ahead?

Comment: @aschipfl; $O\equiv2S\pmod{10}$ is even, and $I\equiv2O\pmod{10}$, therefore $I\equiv4S\pmod{10}$.

Comment: My point is, how can you exclude a carry to be involved in $I$ at that point already?

Comment: @aschipfl; $I$ is the next digit after $T$ in $I+I=T$, and the carry bit would have to roll over into it, which means that $I$ is now odd.

Answer (score 10):

Could it be

> ```
>    1246 
>
>  + 1246 
>
>  ------ 
>
>    2492
> ```

Then

> D=1, O=2, I=4, S=6, T=9

Comment: Perfect! Easy one?

Comment: Not super easy, but there were a limited number of combinations to try. Good puzzle @Chaotic!

Answer (score 1):

Although this post is quite similar to [JMP](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11497)'s [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/80849), I still want to share it here:

> 4<sup>th</sup> column: $O = 2 S$, therefore $O$ is even.
>  1<sup>st</sup> column: $D < 5$, because $2 D < 10$.
>  2<sup>nd</sup> column: $2 O$ must not carry, hence $O < 5$, so either $O = 2$ or $O = 4$.
>  4<sup>th</sup> column: Therefore $D = O / 2$, so either $1$ or $2$.
>  1<sup>st</sup> column: $S = D + 5$, so $2 S$ will carry and will make $T$ odd.
>  3<sup>rd</sup> column: $I \neq 9$, because then $2 I + 1 = 19$, leading to duplicate $T = 9$ as well.
>  3<sup>rd</sup> column: $I \neq 8$, because then $2 I + 1 = 17$, and the carry would force $I$ odd.
>  Hence $O \neq 4$, so the only possibility left is $O = 2$.
>  Thus, $D = 1$, $S = D + 5 = 6$, $I = 2 O = 4$ and $T = 2 I + 1 = 9 $.

Therefore, the result is:

> $1246$
>  $1246$
>  --------
>  $2492$

Answer (score 0):

Let's start as a basic Brute Force

> ```
> Consider D as 1
>
>  Since D and S gives a Unit Place as O
>
>  So,S is D+5 ;S is 6
>
>  So, Here O is 2
>
>  Given I = O + O;     So,I=4
>
>  Since T is I+I with a carry of 1 ;T is 9
> ```